# PHP SQL - Select data efficiently from two tables

Tags: php, sql

Let's say I have these two tables:
[image: Example Tables]

In PHP I want to create an object called '**Foo**' which contains the TagName, the Display and an array of the numbers which are assigned to that tagname..

If I would query for the tagName 'bar' I would get a display with 'Bar Foo Ipsum' and the numbers 33 and 545.

Currently I do it like so:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM DetailsTable");
$stmt->execute();
$details = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM NumbersTable");
$stmt->execute();
$numbers = $stmt->fetchAll();
$myObjects = array();
foreach($details as $detail){
   $foo = new Foo($detail['TagName'], $detail['Display']);
   foreach($numbers as $number){
       if($number['TagName'] == $detail['TagName']){
           $foo.appendNumber($number['Numbers']);
       }
   }
   array_push($myObjects, $foo);
}

class Foo {
   private $tag, $display;
   private $numbers = array();

   public function __construct($tag, $display){
       $this->tag = $tag;
       $this->display = $display;
   }

   /** Insert getters and setters  */
   public function appendNumber($n){
       array_push($this->numbers, $n);
   }
}
```

The code above is pseudo code so I didnt code it yet, but it is the code I most likely would've written. I wanted to ask first so hence the question.

Basically the object Foo should have the TagName and the DisplayName and an array with the numbers that are in a different table. **The TagName is unique in the DetailsTable.**

**TL;DR**: Get  details from `DetailsTable` and the numbers connected to it in the `NumbersTable` and put it in an object.

Comment: You should really look into Foreign Key! Then you can join the two tables more easily

Comment: Foreign key and join statement is the key to your problems!

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? You already got tables, so simply join them using @Caius's Left Join (adding `WHERE TagName = 'Bar'` for a specific tag).  Btw, the `id` column in your NumbersTable is useless (it's probably an auto-generated sequence and never used in any other place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let the SQL engine do the work of matching the records from both tables, it is where it is good at.

Your code would then look somewhat like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT    d.TagName, d.Display, n.Numbers 
                      FROM      DetailsTable d
                      LEFT JOIN NumbersTable n
                             ON n.TagName = d.TagName");
$stmt->execute();
$currentTag = "";
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $record) {
    if ($record['TagName'] !== $currentTag) {
        $myObjects[] = $foo = new Foo($currentTag = $record['TagName'], $record['Display']);
    }
    $foo.appendNumber($record['Numbers']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could solve this with a Left Join

Something like this maybe?

`SELECT * FROM NumbersTable LEFT JOIN DetailsTable ON NumbersTable.TagName = DetailsTable.TagName`